# need a method for json string which contains null value and does not contain attributes{ }

Tags: apex, json

please help me, I need a method for json string which contains null value and does not contain attributes{ }.

Here's what I currently have:

```
List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id, Name, account.name,account.Id,account.ParentId FROM Contact limit 3];
system.debug(json.serialize(contacts));
```

which returns a jsonString that looks like this:

```
 "attributes" : {
    "type" : "Contact",
    "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Contact/003900000115sPwAAI"
  },
  "Name" : "Rose Gonzalez",
  "AccountId" : "00190000010GvcLAAS",
  "Account" : {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Account",
      "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Account/00190000010GvcLAAS"
    },
    "Name" : "Edge Communications",
    "Id" : "00190000010GvcLAAS"
  },
  "Id" : "003900000115sPwAAI"
}, {
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "Contact",
    "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Contact/003900000115sPxAAI"
  },
  "Name" : "Sean Forbes",
  "AccountId" : "00190000010GvcLAAS",
  "Account" : {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Account",
      "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Account/00190000010GvcLAAS"
    },
    "Name" : "Edge Communications",
    "Id" : "00190000010GvcLAAS"
  },
  "Id" : "003900000115sPxAAI"
}, {
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "Contact",
    "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Contact/003900000115sPyAAI"
  },
  "Name" : "Jack Rogers",
  "AccountId" : "00190000010GvcMAAS",
  "Account" : {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Account",
      "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Account/00190000010GvcMAAS"
    },
    "Name" : "Burlington Textiles Corp of America",
    "Id" : "00190000010GvcMAAS"
  },
  "Id" : "003900000115sPyAAI"
} ]
```

What I need is help putting what I've written above into something that will return a string in a format that looks like what's below:

```
 {
  "Name" : "Rose Gonzalez",
  "AccountId" : "00190000010GvcLAAS",
  "Account" : {    
    "Name" : "Edge Communications",
    "Id" : "00190000010GvcLAAS",
   "ParentId":null

  },
  "Id" : "003900000115sPwAAI"
}, {

  "Name" : "Sean Forbes",
  "AccountId" : "00190000010GvcLAAS",
  "Account" : {

    "Name" : "Edge Communications",
    "Id" : "00190000010GvcLAAS",
    "ParentId" :null
  },
  "Id" : "003900000115sPxAAI"
}, {

  "Name" : "Jack Rogers",
  "AccountId" : "00190000010GvcMAAS",
  "Account" : {

    "Name" : "Burlington Textiles Corp of America",
    "Id" : "00190000010GvcMAAS",
    "ParentId" :null
  },
  "Id" : "003900000115sPyAAI"
} ]
```

Comment: can you provide more details on what you need ? like what's your current json string structure is , where you are trying to do this , your existing code if possible ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a post that explains the reason:

[JSON.Serialize method not returning null fields](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/6192/json-serialize-method-not-returning-null-fields)

The fix, version your Apex before Spring 13' I believe it is v 25 or like in the post v27 post fix. I believe since then they have again instituted the change to not serialize nulls

Or you will have to write your own serializer using `JSONGenerator` methods and the `writeNull()` functions:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_System_JsonGenerator.htm